# Getting a parsing error with an axios post request call and i cant figure out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have the following axios request with a parsing error on the console.log call within the .then method with the ;

here is my request:

```
axios.post('/reservations', {
            name:'omar jandali',
            email:'omar@omnacore.com',
            phone:'9515343666'
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('response' + JSON.stringify(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Create reservation error: " + err);
        })
```

I have no idea why this is happening and how ot fix it.

Comment: what's the error ? can you see the data you're receiving in the network tab in the dev console ?

Comment: JSON.stringify or JSON.parse?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing parenthesis for your `console.log`:

```
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('response' + JSON.stringify(res.data));
        })
```